# How to automatically answer with yes through a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

My code is as follows:

```
@echo off

start /d "C:\Users\tawfik\Desktop\ZC90 - Copy" zc90.xls

start /d "C:\Users\tawfik\Desktop\ZC90 - Copy" zc90p.xls

start /d "C:\Users\tawfik\Desktop\ZC90 - Copy" zl10.xls

@echo off
```

When the excel file opens it shows a message with a yes, no or cancel options, I want the code to automatically answer with "Yes" for each file.

Comment: You are doing it stupidly, just put the full path to the file name. Excel doesn't prompt when opening file normally so fix that.

Comment: And, Why is excel asking? What is the text in the message?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
explorer "C:\Users\tawfik\Desktop\ZC90 - Copy\zc90.xls"
explorer "C:\Users\tawfik\Desktop\ZC90 - Copy\zc90p.xls"
explorer "C:\Users\tawfik\Desktop\ZC90 - Copy\zl10.xls"
```